# Why are Types disappearing from Eclipse m2e classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

Once a week to several times a day I have the issue of Types disappearing from the project classpath in my m2e imported projects. I find little or no advice on the problem googling, yet it happens to me on several different maven single and multi-module projects, several versions of Eclipse and in different OS's, for a few years.

All of a sudden, out of the blue, defined Types can not be resolved. Sometimes it happens to Types within the same project. Once it even happen to java.lang.String!

[image: screenshot example]

- The same project takes a `clean install` in Maven 3 just fine (this does not fix the issue in Eclipse).
- I can fix it by cutting the import statements out and back into the java file. But on a large project this is tedious.
- I can fix it by deleting the associated run configurations, deleting the project and then reimporting the project.

I have given Eclipse an absurd amount of memory (4GB) to no avail. Is there anyway to stop this? I'm really tired of it.

[.project](http://pastebin.com/1104ReSg)
[.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs](http://pastebin.com/z3EphnTL)
[.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs](http://pastebin.com/XSNhSh4p)
[.classpath](http://pastebin.com/Rajnp99U)

Comment: post your `.classpath` and `.project` file for project

Comment: it might not be visible in eclipse package/project explorer view, can you check it externally from terminal

Comment: There should be a .classpath file, which will have "pom.derived" entries telling eclipse where to obtain the classpath. Also, does your project have the little M in its icon that indicates it is an M2E project? I've also had this problem, but a Project/Clean usually fixes it.

Comment: There is a small M on the imported projects. I have had this happen in  several different single and multimodule maven projects.